# Make server keep listening for inputstreams using DataInputStream

Tags: java, sockets

I created a java class TCPClient which sends Message objects to the TCPServer. I use DataOutputStream and DataInputstream (This is a task we were told to do so, we have to use both of them in order to send an Object from client to server).
This is my TCPClient class

```
public class TCPClient {
public static final int PORT = 4000;
public static void main(String[] args){
    String hostname = "localhost";
    try(Socket client = new Socket(hostname,PORT);
        //BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {

        Message message;
        String input;
        String the_message;
        double random;
        int id;
        while(!(input = stdIn.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("end")){
            random =  Math.random()*100;
            message = new Message();
            the_message = input;
            id = (int)random;
            message.setId(id);
            message.setMessage(the_message);
            encode(message,client);
            //System.out.println(in.readLine());
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private static void encode(Message message, Socket client) {
    try(DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())){
        out.writeUTF(message.getMessage());
        out.writeInt(message.getId());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

TCPServer class

```
public class TCPServer {
public static final int PORT = 4000;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT);
         Socket cs = ss.accept();
         //PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(cs.getOutputStream(), true);
    ) {
        Message message = decode(cs);
        System.out.print("Message received: " + message.getMessage() + " id: " + message.getId());



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
private static Message decode(Socket client){
    Message message = new Message();
    try(DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream())){
       message.setMessage(in.readUTF());
        message.setId(in.readInt());
        return message;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("Error happened while decoding object");
        return null;
    }
}}
```

What I DONT want to do is that when I send a new message from Client the Server closes. I want the server to keep listening for Messages. How do I accomplish that?

Tried something like this

```
while(cs.getInputStream().available()==0){
            Message message = decode(cs);
            System.out.println("Message received = " + message.getMessage() + " id " + message.getId());
        }
```

But didnt work

EDIT: I dont want to build a multi-threaded server to host several clients. I want a single server to receive several messages from a unique client and close the socket whenever the client sends "end", I dont know if thats possible.

Comment: you want the client to send one or multiple Messages, and the server to listen to all of them, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your client sends up to only one message, because `encode()` closes the socket by closing the socket output stream. If you want the client to send multiple Messages, try something like this:

```java
public class TCPClient {
    // ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket client = new Socket(hostname, PORT);
             BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
             DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream())) {
            // ...
            while (!(input = stdIn.readLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                // ...
                encode(message, out);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void encode(Message message, DataOutputStream out) throws IOException {
        out.writeUTF(message.getMessage());
        out.writeInt(message.getId());
    }
}
```

The server also receives up to one message because `decode()` closes the socket by closing its input stream. This should do it:

```java
public class TCPServer {
    // ...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
            // Accepts infinite clients.
            while (true) {
                try (Socket cs = ss.accept();
                     DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream())) {
                    boolean isClientOpen = true;
                    while (isClientOpen) {
                        try {
                            Message message = decode(in);
                            System.out.print("Message received: " + message.getMessage() + " id: " + message.getId());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // The client may have closed the socket.
                            isClientOpen = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Message decode(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
        Message message = new Message();
        message.setMessage(in.readUTF());
        message.setId(in.readInt());
        return message;
    }
}
```